# PHP glob does not show files / directories with non-standard characters

Tags: php, debian, glob

Why glob doesn't show files or directories with unicode characters? How do I list those files with PHP?

Example:

"REGA�_10"

I know that those names are invalid, but Debian can create and list them... so why glob doesn't ?

Comment: that's not PHP, that's a display issue with whatever environment you're outputting the strings into.e.g. it may be a UTF filename, but your printing the string in iso-8859-1

Comment: but PHP doesn't list that dir AT ALL and I am printing it in UTF8, it was encoded wrong by WinSCP, but that is not the point... the point is that glob does not list such files.

Comment: `glob('data/*')` ... what glob code? Example I given in question is name of directory that is not being displayed by glob. I know it has unknown utf character, and it does have it in real filesystem... midnight shows it as square... on windows it was "Ł", but when copying to Debian via SFTP it was being converted to unknown utf8 character, as on Windows filenames are CP1250 encoded. But on Windows, xampp php doesn't read those neither. All other dirs / files are displayed. Other - the ones without any non-alphanumeric characters.